# GROUP BY and AS column

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have a set of records and I would like to group them by day using a `DATETIME` field at this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

In MySQL, `GROUP BY` uses results of the `SELECT` query and applies a `GROUP BY` at this moment:

```
SELECT date(date_field) AS d, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY d;
```

OrientDB seems to don't apply the `GROUP BY` on results:

```
SELECT date_field.format('yyyy-MM-dd') AS d, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY d;
```

This Query returns nothing because `d` is not in same format as `date_field`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: try `GROUP BY date_field.format('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: That doesn't work in orientDB.

Answer (score 2):

Your data format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

The day comes in place 9 from left, so you can use the query

```
SELECT date_field  FROM my_table GROUP BY LEFT(`date_field`, 9);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks, That doesn't work on OrientDB. I get this error: `Error on parsing command at position #40: Invalid keyword 'DATE_FIELD'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using LET variables:

```
SELECT date_field, COUNT(*) FROM my_table LET $day =  date_field.format('yyyy-MM-dd') GROUP BY $day;
```